# Chart annotations: How can I align the annotation along an axis of a datapoint

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts

I have aligned the annotations to data points; I want to align the annotations vertically.

I have read this, But can't figure out how to relate the chart width to data points. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456731.aspx

And this: [MS Charting Annotations refuse to align to mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366866/ms-charting-annotations-refuse-to-align-to-mouse-position/25367132#25367132)

I added a picture of the chart so far as an example.

[image]

```
'create new chart
 chart1 = New DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

 'add chart areas
  chart1.ChartAreas.Add("NewChartArea")
  chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = False
  chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False 'turn chart background grid on and off
  chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False 'turn chart background grid on and off
  chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisX.Title = "Activities of daily living" '----> title on the bottom for the x axis
  '[template] chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45
  '[template] Chart1.Series(SeriesZeroChartName).Label = " my own label" ' -----> adds a label at the top of each bar

   For c As Integer = 2 To Me.DataGridViewResultsAdls.ColumnCount - 1

        Dim NextSeriesChartName As String
        NextSeriesChartName = DataGridViewResultsAdls.Columns(c).Name

        chart1.Series.Add(NextSeriesChartName)
        chart1.Series(NextSeriesChartName).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar 'CHART CHANGER ******  change this value to change chart type
        chart1.Series(NextSeriesChartName).Points.Clear()
        chart1.Series(NextSeriesChartName).IsValueShownAsLabel = True '----> puts little labels ontop of each bar
        chart1.Series(NextSeriesChartName).SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = True


       ' fill each subsequent series with points
         For Count As Integer = 0 To DataGridViewResultsAdls.Rows.Count - 2
                Dim NextColumnName As String
                NextColumnName = DataGridViewResultsAdls.Columns(c).Name

                ' define X values
                Dim XLabelMyCustom As String
                XLabelMyCustom = DataGridViewResultsAdls.Item(0, Count).Value
                'define Y values
                Dim YLabelMyCustom As String
                YLabelMyCustom = DataGridViewResultsAdls.Item(NextColumnName, Count).Value

                ' add the point to the chart
                chart1.Series(NextSeriesChartName).Points.AddXY(XLabelMyCustom, YLabelMyCustom)

                ' create custom labels for the x axis
                chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(Count + 0.5, Count + 0.4 + 0.5, "Q2", 0, DataVisualization.Charting.LabelMarkStyle.None)
                chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(Count + 0.5 + 0.5, Count + 0.9 + 0.5, "Q1", 0, DataVisualization.Charting.LabelMarkStyle.None)
                chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(Count + 0.5, Count + 1, "Q3", 2, DataVisualization.Charting.LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark)



                'Create a variable MyDataPoint to hold the current datapoint
                Dim MyDataPoint As DataPoint
                MyDataPoint = chart1.Series(NextSeriesChartName).Points(Count)
                'Create a new text annotation
                Dim MyTextAnnotation As TextAnnotation
                MyTextAnnotation = New TextAnnotation
                MyTextAnnotation.Text = "some notation"
                '[template] MyTextAnnotation.X =   <---- sets coordinates on screen for x
                '[template ]MyTextAnnotation.Y =   <---- sets coordinates on screen for y
                '[template] MyTextAnnotation.AnchorDataPoint = MyDataPoint  'sets the point where the notation will be
                '[template] chart1.Annotations.Add(MyTextAnnotation) ' adds the notation to the chart

                ' only add annotations to the chart once per series
                If c = 2 Then
                    MyTextAnnotation.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas("NewChartArea").AxisY

                    ' [template] chart1.Series(NextSeriesChartName).Points.Item(Count).ToString  <--- output points to a string {x,y}


                    MyTextAnnotation.AnchorDataPoint = MyDataPoint  'sets the point where the notation will be
                    chart1.Annotations.Add(MyTextAnnotation) ' adds the notation to the chart
                    MyTextAnnotation.AnchorOffsetX = -10


                End If
            Next

        Next

        'Add chart to control and set dock to fill
        Me.PanelChartAdls.Controls.Add(chart1)
        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    End If
```

Comment: Can you draw the positions you want into your screenshot? (Nice [Red Circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta), btw..) - You probably need some [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.anchoroffsety%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: :)  I did, the position where I would like the annotations is on the yellow highlight :)
I tried using the off set, but am unsure how to calculate it accurately as the data points use a % representative of the chart height and width

Comment: Also the x axis is vertical on this chart, as it is a bar chart, so the X-axis of the plot points relates to the height of the chart - i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positioning in a `Chart` control is rather complex.

To begin with a chart has **three** coordinate systems:

- The data values
- Percentages of some area, most notably the `ChartArea` and the `InnerPlotPosition`
- Pixels of the `Chart` control's `ClientArea`

The simplest way to achieve an alignment of your `Annotations` is to first anchor each to its `DataPoint`:

```
MyTextAnnotation.AnchorDataPoint = MyDataPoint
```

Next you override the X-Position to a **value** you like:

```
MyTextAnnotation.X = someValue;
```

A few notes:

- While by **default** the `Annotation.Position` would use `percentages`, after **anchoring** it to a **DataPoint** it uses the **values** instead. So using `50` would not place in somewhere around the middle but all to the right...

Looking at your Chart I suggest using a value of `3`.

- If your values vary this positioning will also vary. And when you resize the Chart the Axes will be resized and the Annotations will move as well.

Btw: The percentages are in relation to the next outer container: The `ChartAreas` to the `Chart.ClientRectangle`, the `InnerPlotPostion` to the `ChartArea` and each element to the container it is docked to..

- The `Positions` are by default set to automatic so their values are `NaN`. To access the (current) values you can call `ElementPosition.ToRectangleF()`.
- Also note that there are several functions on the `Chart's Axes` that will convert values, pixels and percent-positions.

However you need to find a valid **moment** to call those functions; if the `Chart` is not done with its layout, they will return `null`.

You can safely either call them in one of the three `Paint` events or in response to a user interaction like a Mouse event.

Here is how to use them for positioning all `Annotations` to a (somewhat) fixed pixel position:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Axis AY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

    double pypx = AY.ValueToPosition(AY.PixelPositionToValue(30));

    foreach (TextAnnotation ta in chart1.Annotations)
    {
        ta.X = pypx;
    }
}
```

Now the `Annotations` will not move when the chart is resized or when the data values grow or shrink. At least not a lot; a few jumps can be seen. Either because I missed something or because of rounding issues.

But I suggest going with the simpler method of setting their X-Position to a fixed value on your axis..:

```
MyTextAnnotation.X = 3;
```

This would put them at the yellow line you drew.

Comment: ! Thank You So Much ! That answer is great on so many levels. I really appreciate the time taken.

Comment: Could you recommend resources so I may learn more about the charting process above ?

Comment: Not really beyond MSDN, as the Chart control is not well documented and what I know was learned by searching high and low. You may want to read through a couple of [SO posts of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3152130%20ChartArea) though that deal with these issues.. (The more recent they are, the more I knew when I wrote them ;-)

Comment: Could i trouble you for an example of how to calculate percentages ? or a resource for that, I am quite interested in the topic

Comment: To get a percentage aka position from a datavalue you use the ValueToPosition fuction. To get it from pixels you need to combine it with PixelPositionToValue. Both are shown in the last piece of code. If you want to you can also get the pixelwidth of the innerplotposition and use it to calculate the percentages from a pixel size you want.. Among the linked posts [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491231/ms-chart-rectangular-annotation-width-in-percent-and-not-pixel/36497262?s=5|0.0000#36497262) calculates percent from pixels.