# how to align polyline annotation with respect to graph point in ms chart

Tags: c#, winforms, annotations, mschart

I had added Polyline annotation to graph control. But it is not aligned properly in given datapoint in Addline() method.

```
        PolylineAnnotation annotation = new PolylineAnnotation();
        annotation.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        annotation.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
        annotation.AnchorX = 0;
        annotation.AnchorY = 0;
        annotation.Height = 30;
        annotation.Width = -30;
        annotation.LineWidth = 3;
        annotation.StartCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
        annotation.EndCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
        annotation.Alignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
        annotation.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
        annotation.AnchorDataPoint = new DataPoint(this.chart1.Series[0]);

        annotation.AllowAnchorMoving = true;
        annotation.AllowMoving = true;
        annotation.AllowPathEditing = true;
        annotation.AllowResizing = true;
        annotation.AllowSelecting = true;

        annotation.GraphicsPath.AddLine(10, 20, 30, 30);
        chart1.Annotations.Add(annotation);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: still .I am not get solutions for that problem. Right now I am looking for similar chart control with annotations functionality either in winform or wpf.

Comment: Is anything in my post unclear? Adding the rectangle is very helpful to understand your situation!

Comment: your solution really helpful for me. But this ms chart control does not fit into my application requirement. Thank for replying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Annotations` are **complex** and anchoring them is too.

**It starts rather simple**: To anchor an `Annotation` you need to set its `AnchorDataPoint` to an **existing** `DataPoint`.

This line does nothing like that:

```
annotation.AnchorDataPoint = new DataPoint(this.chart1.Series[0]);
```

as the newly created `DataPoint` is empty. Its has been added and it has values of `(0d, 0d)`, but you probably want to keep the `Annotation` aligned to a **real** `DataPoint`, maybe like this..:

```
annotation.AnchorDataPoint = chart1.Series[0].Points[someIndex];
```

**But there is more**: There actually are **two** ways to anchor an `Annotation`:

- Anchor it to a `DataPoint` or
- Anchor it with fixed `AnchorX` and `AnchorY` values.

(And then you can set them to fixed X & Y values, too.)

Your code actually does both! **But**: anchoring the coordinates takes **precedence** over anchoring to a `DataPoint`.

This is nice as you can combine them and first anchor to a `DataPoint` and then anchor **one** of the coordinates to a fixed value: say, x-value stays with the point but the y-value is maybe always at 0..

Also note that you are adding only one line to your polyline and you don't start it at `(0,0)` but at `(10,20)` which **may** be quite some way off the anchor..

**And then** there is the issue of **size** and **alignment** of the polyline itself!

It has a size which [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) **claims** is given in pixels. This is **nonsense**. Instead it is given in `value` units of the two respective `Axes`. You can see this when you **resize** the `Chart` the `Annotation` will resize as well; see the screenshot!

**Now** for the `GraphicsPath` and its points: Those are given in **percent** of the `Size` of the `Annotation`. To get a feeling for this add a test annotation path that encloses the whole area:

```
 annotation.GraphicsPath.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
```

Here is a screenshot of what we have got:

[image]

As you can see the most logical alignment is `TopLeft` and after translating the line to `(0,0)` it would stick right into the point.

Note that I have added a 2nd `Series` to make the anchor data point stand out.. - Also note that while the `Annotation` size is a **square** `(10,10)` is is **stretched** horizontally along with the whole **chart**.

This is the full code I used:

```
PolylineAnnotation annotation = new PolylineAnnotation();
annotation.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
annotation.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

annotation.Height = 10;
annotation.Width = 10;
annotation.LineWidth = 3;
annotation.StartCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
annotation.EndCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.None;
annotation.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
annotation.AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;

annotation.X = annotation.Y = annotation.AnchorX = annotation.AnchorY = double.NaN;

DataPoint dp = chart1.Series[0].Points[33];
annotation.AnchorDataPoint = dp;
chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(dp.XValue, dp.YValues[0]);  // my red points series

annotation.AllowAnchorMoving = true;
annotation.AllowMoving = true;
annotation.AllowPathEditing = true;
annotation.AllowResizing = true;
annotation.AllowSelecting = true;

annotation.GraphicsPath.AddLine(10, 20, 30, 30);
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
annotation.GraphicsPath.AddRectangle(r);

chart1.Annotations.Add(annotation);
```

Also note that just to make sure no wrong anchors are active I have **reset** the `X/Y` and the `AnchorX/Y` values by setting them to `double.NaN`! This is not really needed here, as those are the defaults anyway..

[Here btw is another post on the topic!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024717/chart-annotations-how-can-i-align-the-annotation-along-an-axis-of-a-datapoint)